# replace() function works in VS Studio (React native), but fails on iPhone?

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, xcode, react-native

I have a function which works perfectly in Javascript on my iPhone simulator on the Mac. When i transfer this via Xcode to an physical iPhone handset, the .replace() function doesn't work. I get the error: TypeError: null is not an object (data.replace) not evaluating

```
await this.getAsyncStorage(this.state.username)
            .then(data => this.setState({localname: data.replace(/\"/g, "") }) );
```

So i get a returned id ("hiuhiu22-sdwdw343-fgrh6576") from AsyncStorage when i supply the `this.state.username` key. The `replace()` strips " " off the ends of `"hiuhiu22-sdwdw343-fgrh6576"` to get just `hiuhiu22-sdwdw343-fgrh6576`, so that i can use `localname` in another function, which MUST have them stripped off.

Why isn't it working on the actual iPhone?

Comment: perhaps when you switch it to xcode, you not longer have access to your storage?? that error is resulting from the fact that data is undefined, so, perhaps you need to check your connection to storage, and see if you can get it to return anything... check your storage configs, and make sure your xcode project is set to handle it.

Comment: You're right. I just tried to show the data (before i do data.replace() ) in an alert window and its blank! Any idea how i get the Asyncstorage properly setup?

Comment: it looks like this is a known bug with react-native and ios. https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage/issues/86